# Unique Root of a DoG filter

Tags: filters, difference-of-gaussians

I have a mathematics problem that can be related to Signal Processing. Let $f$ be a real function, striclty increasing, striclty convex on $(-\infty,0)$, strictly concave on $(0,\infty)$. We furthermore assume $f$ to be smooth and integrable w.r.t gaussian kernel.

My problem is the following, can one show that for $\sigma_1>\sigma_2>0$, the function defined by:

$$\Delta := f*(G_{\sigma_1}-G_{\sigma_2}) $$

has a unique root on $\mathbb{R}$ ? I am, at least numerically, quite sure that it is true.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that the [Difference of Gaussians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians) (DoG) is an approximation of the [Laplacian of Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection#The_Laplacian_of_Gaussian) (LoG) which is basically smoothed [Laplace Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) (Laplacian).

For 1D signal it is basically the 2nd derivative.
Your function, since it has a convex section and concave section, has a single [Inflection Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) where the curvature changes sign.
This happens exactly where the function changes from convex to concave.

Comment: Thank you @Royi for your answer. I see that the uniqueness of inflection point implies uniqueness of a root for the Laplacian operator (the very definition). But how can I proove that it is also true for the smoothed Laplacian ?  Then, How can I show that is is true for my function ?

Comment: I think you can show that the integral with a Gaussian and a even-symmetry function must be non-zero (positive or negative depends on the convexity or concavity).  The integral of the Gaussian multiplying an odd-symmetry function is zero.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I don't think the function has to be symmetric. Just convex and concave. Symmetry will means the values are the same up to a sign.

Comment: @Gaetano, One way to show it is by using linearity. The DoG / LoG are linear operations over the Laplacian. Hence the must map zero to zero. This will give you the existence. To show uniqueness, you may try to think of the kernel and show why it can not happen in your case.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson thank you, as Royi said, I think it is true also for concave/convex functions.

Comment: Thank you @Royi, for the existence I think I have it by considering a Taylor expansion of the DoG function. I am now struggling on the uniqueness. I have tried many ways of proving but I can't see the property of the DoG function that makes the uniqueness true. Could you give me an hint about proving the uniqueness please ? Thank you !

Comment: @Gaetano, Linearity. If it was zero for the LoG it must be zero for the Laplacian -> Contradiction as there is only a single inflection point.

Comment: Thank you @Roy but I really don't understand, I am sorry if I ask stupid questions but I want to be sure that I understand well. I am missing two points in your proof:
1. How a zero in gaussian laplacian implies a zero in laplacian ?
2. How a zero in DoG implies a zero in gaussian Laplacian ? 
Thank you again for taking time and sorry to ask naive questions.

(I tried to proove this two points but without success for now...)

Comment: @Gaetano. You go the other way around. If you do Laplacian, is it clear to you how to show there is a single zero? OK, now the zero is also a zero of the LoG since it is a linear operator on top of the Laplacian. Now you do assumption, assuming there is another zero, of the LoG -> It must be also a zero of the Laplacian -> Contradiction.

Comment: I am trying to follow your ideas: we have $x_0$ the inflection point of $f''$. We denote the laplacian $\Delta$. By definition, we have $\Delta (f)(x_0)=0$ (single zero point of $\Delta (f)$). Since the LoG is linear on top of the Laplcian, we have $\text{LoG}(\Delta)(f)(x_0) = 0$. Now, if we assume that there exists another $x_1$ such that $\text{LoG}(f)(x_1) = 0$, we can only say that $\Delta(\text{LoG})(f)(x_1) = 0$, how can we say that $x_1$ is then a 0 of $\Delta(f)$ ?

Comment: @Gaetano, This is the something you need to do. It will require some simple work. Start with assuming the Laplacian is not 0. It also not zero around. Now build the constraints to have zeros (Sum of the gaussian). Since you have convex and concave you know the sign of the values. If it is all negative, or positive you know it can't be zero. Now you need to build the case of both. So you need the weighted sum to be zero. It will have constraints. Anyhow, I gave all I think needed to solve.

Comment: //" I don't think the function has to be symmetric. Just convex and concave. Symmetry will means the values are the same up to a sign."// But @Royi, every function can be decomposed into an even-symmetry component and an odd-symmetry component. I never said that the concave or convex part had to be either even or odd.  I am saying that the odd-symmetry part will have an integral of zero and that the even-symmetry part will have a **non-zero** integral (and whether it's positive or negative depends on whether it's concave or convex).

Comment: @Gaetano, you should express your problem explicitly, mathematically.  Show the integral with the concave/convex function along with the Gaussian function.  Then I will show you how the even-symmetry *component* will integrate to something non-zero and the odd-symmetry *component* will always integrate to zero.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, thank you for your answer. I wrote some maths in answer so that it will be more confortable to read. (I will let you write the answer again to give you reputations :) )

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, feel free to edit the answer or write down another one

Comment: @Royi, I finaly learned to prove that two zeros in gaussian laplacian imply two zeros in laplacian. But to be honest, after working a lot I really can't find out how to show the first part, i.e., two zeros in DoG imply two zeros in LoG. Do you have an idea or a reference where there is a comparable method that I could apply to prove this ?

Comment: @Gaetano, I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Royi, I want to prove that 2 zeros in DoG imply two zeros in LoG, that imply 2 zeros in Laplacian. I have proved the final step (two zeros in LoG imply two zeros in Laplcian). Now I have to prove that 2 zeros in DoG imply two zeros in LoG. As Isaid, I have absolutely no clue to link LoG and DoG mathematicaly.

Comment: I just have that LoG is the limit of DoG with the same $\sigma$, but I have two fixed $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ for the DoG function.

Comment: @Royi, for this step, I could also prove that if the LoG has only one zero, the DoG must have a unique 0... I have no clue for both of these proofs...

Comment: @Royi, I asked the question https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/88935/link-between-roots-of-difference-of-gaussian-and-laplacian-of-gaussian , since it's not exactly the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I want to prove that $\Delta$ has only one zero if $f$ has only one inflection point.

More precisely:

$$\delta(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma_1}\int_\mathbb{R}f(s)e^{-\frac{(s-x)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}}ds-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma_2}\int_\mathbb{R}f(s)e^{-\frac{(s-x)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}}ds$$

should have only one zeros. We define $g(s) \triangleq f(s + x)$. We then have by change of variable:

$$\delta(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}(g(\sigma_1 s)-g(\sigma_2 s))e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}ds.$$

We can decompose $g = g_e + g_o$ with:

$$g_e(s) \triangleq \frac{g(s)+g(-s)}{2},~g_o(s) \triangleq \frac{g(s)-g(-s)}{2}.$$

The "odd" part always integrate to zeros (product of even and odd function), we have then to show that:

$$\begin{align}
\delta(x) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}(g_e(\sigma_1 s)-g_e(\sigma_2 s))e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}ds \\
&= \Delta(\sigma_1,x)-\Delta(\sigma_2,x) \\
\end{align}$$

Where both $\sigma_1>0$ and $\sigma_2>0$ and the two-variable $\Delta(\cdot,\cdot)$ is

$$ \Delta(\sigma, x) \triangleq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_\mathbb{R} g_e(\sigma s) e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}ds $$

Now, as long as $x$ is fixed, the sign of $\Delta(\sigma, x)$ cannot change for any $\sigma>0$.  If $\Delta(\sigma_1, x)>0$, so also is $\Delta(\sigma_2, x)$.

Comment: Why are there two integrals with two different $\sigma$'s?  They are both centered at $x$, so their only difference is their $\sigma$.  Now, my point is made when you change the variable so that the Gaussians are centered at $0$ and $f(s)$ is offset by $x$.  So you split $g(s) \triangleq f(s+x)$ into even and odd components (as functions of $s$.  Then you have an even part of $g(s)$ against against an even-symmetry Gaussian (which is even and will integrate to something non-zero) and an odd part of $g(s)$ multiplied by the Gaussian (which is odd and will integrate to zero).

Comment: Both $f(\sigma_1 s+x)$ and $f(\sigma_2 s+x)$ are either concave or convex about $s=0$.  You can't have $f(\sigma_1 s+x)$ be concave and $f(\sigma_2 s+x)$ be convex (about $s=0$) for the same value of $x$.

Comment: Thank you @robertbristow-johnson for your detailed explanations. I am sorry but I can't see how I can use your comments to solve the problem. Could you explain me a little more your idea ? Thank you !

Comment: Concerning your second comment, I don't understand because we now talking about the even part of $f$...

Comment: I am talking about the even and odd parts of $g(s) \triangleq f(\sigma s + x)$  ***not*** the even part of $f(s)$.  I.e. look at the function that is directly multiplying the Gaussian kernel $e^{-s^2/2}$ that is centered at $s=0$.  The even part of $g(s)$ will integrate to something nonzero.  The odd part of $g(s)$ will integrate to zero.

Comment: Thank you @robertbristow-johnson, I edited the post with your recommendations. However I am still not able to see how can I have information about the sign of $\Delta$ just considering the fact that is convex and concave. Thank you so much for your patience !

Comment: well, patience all around, because I am still tossing stuff up against the wall.

Comment: Thank you for editing. I changed $\Delta$ in $\delta$ to avoid any confusions at the begining. How do you have that $\Delta(x,\sigma)$ has the same sign for all $\sigma>0$ ?

Comment: Re @robertbristow-johnson, I have worked a lot on your hint but I am quite struggling and stuck. I have to admit that I can't go further... any improvements on your side ?

Comment: I'll have to spend more serious time on it.  I think we need to nail down asymptotic limits and also the constant offset to the function.